# How many CPU processors can be provided by SQL Server 2005 Standard Edition?

Tags: sql-server-2005, cpu-usage

I want to know that how many cpu processor can be provided by MSSQL 2005 Standart Edition? You may suggest a source link. 
When I see server properties, 7 processor seems at there.
But, All processor that seems can be provided mssql 2005 standart edition?

P/S : We have got two processor, Each processor has four core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2005 Standard supports 4 CPUs. Each CPU can be multicore.